# How do I insert a binary file into mongodb using javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to write a script using javascript to insert a binary file into the mongodb.  The file is far less than the [max 16MB limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/), so implementing this with [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) is beyond the scope of the feature I'm writing.

I'm writing the script so I can run it like so:

```
mongo localhost:27017/myMongoDB loadMyFile.js
```

`loadMyFile.js` looks something like this:

```
db.myCollection.insert( {
  fileName: "myFile.ogg",
  file: cat(./myFile.ogg")
});
```

But when I search the collection:

```
db.myCollection.find({
    fileName:"myFile.ogg"
});
```

I get something like:

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("53d2d6c76c694a37315c0195"),
  "fileName": "myFile.ogg",
  "file":"ID3\u0002"
}
```

Which seems wrong.  Please assist.  Thanks in advanced.

Comment: A couple of things. (1) The max is 16MB. I don't know if you made a typo on your post, but it is not GB, but MB. (2) If you're storing a file in MongoDB, you should use GridFS, regardless of its size. It's the best way to store files in MongoDB.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17004242/read-image-file-into-a-mongodb-documents-binary-field-via-mongo-shell-script. Seems like you can't read directly from filesystem to mongodb through the shell. With GridFS you can use mongofiles to insert file data directly from the filesystem. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @[JuanCarlosFarah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1740264/juan-carlos-farah) and @[RobertMunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3444801/robert-munn), GridFS appears to be the best *(and maybe the only?)* way to insert files into the db without writing a small application.

```
mongofiles -d myMongoDB -l myFileName.ogg --type audio/ogg put "The Name of my File in the Collection"
```

See [mongofiles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/) for more more details.